# Need to add multiple divs with same content inside a single div on a click against the parent div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

Here is my piece of code, a function to add a meal template:

```
vm.addMealTemplate = function() {

$scope.mealCount++;
$compile( $(document.createElement('div')).attr("id", 'mealDiv' + $scope.mealCount).addClass("mealDiv"+$scope.mealCount).after().html(
          '<select ng-options="(option.name ) for option in mealOptions" ng-model="selectedOption'+ $scope.mealCount+'" />' +
          '<input type="text" placeholder="Meal timings" id="time'+ $scope.mealCount +'"/>' +
          '<a id="mealCount" ng-class="mealCount" ng-click="addItemCategory()" uib-tooltip="Add category" tooltip-trigger="mouseenter" tooltip-placement="bottom"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>'
        ).appendTo("#meals")
       // $("#meals").append(newMealDiv)
        )($scope);
      }
```

On clicking calling the `addItemCategory()` for the specific `div`, I want another `div` to get added as a child of that `div`. There can be mutiple meal templates, and for each template I can call the `addItemCategory` mutliple times, and I want the category to be added to the same `div` for which the function has been called. How do I achieve this?

Currently I am using `mealCount` variable from scope to have the context, but once it gets increased, I have no way to access the divs added previously, to add the new element to that div. Any way using jQuery or AngularJs?

Comment: Why don't use `ng-repeat` in the view?

Comment: How would that help? Do you mean I should put the whole div inside ng-repeat ?

Comment: Yes, that's right. Do you know how to do this?

Comment: Not really. I am very new to angular and jquery. Could you help me with that please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`ng-repeat`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat)

For example:

```js
angular.module('app', []).
controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.meals = [];
});
```

```css
.meal {
  border:1px solid;
  padding:10px;
  margin-bottom:10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <div ng-repeat="meal in meals" class="meal">
    <select ng-model="meal.count">
      <option>1</option>
      <option>2</option>
      <option>3</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Meal timings" ng-model="meal.timing" />
    <div>
      <div>Categories:</div>
      <div ng-repeat="cat in meal.categories track by $index">
        <input type="text" ng-model="meal.categories[$index]" />
      </div>
      <button ng-click="meal.categories.push('')">Add Category</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button ng-click="meals.push({categories:[]})">Add meal</button>
  <hr />
  {{meals | json}}
</div>
```

**Note:** I changed the models etc. it's just example..

Comment: Thanks for your answer Mosh. However, my real problem is not adding meals, but adding multiple categories inside each meal. I need a way to get the context of the meal div for which the addItemCategory() was called. How do I do that ?

Comment: You can add `ng-repeat` for the categories in `ng-repeat` of the meals. It works the same. I was updated my answer with this functionality.

Comment: Thanks Mosh. This helped me solve my problem to a great extent.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example Plunker on how your problem can be solved with ng-repeat in Angular:

http://plnkr.co/edit/POt7nFc4GqFU67SWdMp7?p=preview

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.5/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="restaurant" ng-controller="meal-controller">
    <div ng-repeat="meal in meals track by $index">
      <select ng-options="option.name for option in mealOptions" ng-model="meal.selectedMeal"></select>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Meal timings" id="{{'time'+ $index }}" ng-model="meal.timing"/>
      <a id="mealCount" ng-class="mealCount" ng-click="addItemCategory()" uib-tooltip="Add category" tooltip-trigger="mouseenter" tooltip-placement="bottom"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>
    </div>

    <button ng-click="addMeal()">Add meal</button>
  </body>

</html>
```

-

```
// Script.js

angular.module('restaurant', [])
    .run( ['$rootScope', function( $rootScope )  {
    }]
);


angular.module('restaurant').controller('meal-controller', [ '$scope', function( $scope ) {

  $scope.meals = [];

  $scope.mealOptions = [{ name: "option1"}, { name: "option2"}, { name: "option3" } ];

  $scope.addMeal = function() {
    $scope.meals.push({ selectedMeal: null, timing: "timing" });
  }

  $scope.addItemCategory = function() {

  }
}]);
```

I am not entirely sure about how you want the logic to work, but I am sure that you can modify this example to fit your needs.

Ng-repeat works like a loop which prints the content it is wrapping until the end of the array. Ng-repeat has a lot of features like tracking elements in the array by index, this can used to (like in the example) give each input an unique id.

If you need to make some specific changes to a meal, you can pass it as an argument, for example if you want to delete a specific meal you can have a button inside the ng-repeat like this:

```
<button ng-click="deleteMeal(meal)">Delete Meal</button>
```

This means that you do not have to access the meal specifically by, for example, its id with jQuery.

I would say it is not recommended to mix angular and jQuery the way you are doing now. Try to stick with Angular and avoid jQuery. In some special cases where you need to do element specific modifications it can be achieved by using jQlite:

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element

Comment: My real problem is to add multiple similar html elements inside each meal, on calling the function addItemCategory() each time. What is the right way to do that ?